# ([core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

Exception has occurred.
FirebaseException ([core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized.

Usually this means you've attempted to use a Firebase service before calling Firebase.initializeApp.

View the documentation for more information: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initialization
)

These are my main.dart code:

```
Future main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    if (kIsWeb) {
        await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: const FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: "AIzaSyDJQ6ymkbfS3YMtGM-jiK2k3sUnHnCQNC8",
        // authDomain: "flutter-ois-fafc4.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "flutter-ois-fafc4",
        // storageBucket: "flutter-ois-fafc4.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "950521712293",
        appId: "1:950521712293:web:d8ac01ada3067c3e7b474c",
        // measurementId: "G-98JPJ4HZGT"
  ));
  } else {
        await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }

  runApp(
  DevicePreview(
  // enabled: true,
  builder: (context) =\> const MyApp(), // Wrap your app
 ),
);
}
```

These are dependencies:

```
firebase_core: ^2.21.0  
firebase_storage: ^11.4.1
firebase_database: ^10.3.3
cloud_firestore: ^4.12.2
firebase_auth: ^4.12.1
```

Answer (score 0):

First connect to your firebase project using CLI. then

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart'

Future main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,);

  runApp(
  DevicePreview(
  // enabled: true,
  builder: (context) =\> const MyApp(), // Wrap your app
 ),
);
}
```